# How to enable text input after clicking a corresponding radio button under Bootstrap 4?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, disabled-input

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and designing a mock item submission form in my web app. In the transaction row, the text input for price is default disabled. What should I do if I enable the text input after clicking the 'sell' button?

```
<div class="form-inline">
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
         <input type="radio" id="free" name="customRadioInline1" class="custom-control-input" checked>
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="free">Free</label>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
         <input type="radio" id="sell" name="customRadioInline1" class="custom-control-input">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="sell">Sell</label>
      </div>
   </div>
   <label for="price">Price</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" placeholder="HKD" disabled>
</div>
```

I expect there will be some code which includes 'onclick' and 'add.eventListener' on the 'sell' radio button when writing JS, but I don't know how to code so that enabling typing the price after selecting  the sell button, and keeping disabled when default (i.e. free).

Or, is there any easy way with Bootstrap 4?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `[...document.querySelectorAll('.custom-control-label')].forEach( e => e.addEventListener('click', function(){ your_Input_Id.focus(); }) );` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first target all the radios with [**`Document.querySelectorAll()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). Then loop through them with [**`forEach()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to attach the event (click). Inside the event handler function you can check the *id* of the clicked radio button based on which you can set/remove the attribute (`disabled`).

**Try following way:**

```js
var radios = document.querySelectorAll('[name=customRadioInline1]');
Array.from(radios).forEach(function(r){
  r.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var priceEl = document.getElementById('price');
    if(this.id == 'sell')
      priceEl.removeAttribute('disabled');
    else
      priceEl.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="form-inline">
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
         <input type="radio" id="free" name="customRadioInline1" class="custom-control-input" checked>
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="free">Free</label>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
         <input type="radio" id="sell" name="customRadioInline1" class="custom-control-input">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="sell">Sell</label>
      </div>
   </div>
   <label for="price">Price</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" placeholder="HKD" disabled>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works!!!!!! BTW would like to know what the this keywords refers to. Is it the variable radios? I always get confused with 'this'......

Comment: @ronzenith, you are most welcome. `this` points to the element on which the event (click) is happened. In the above example, if you click on first radio button `this` points to the first radio button, if you click on the second radio button `this` points to the second radio button:)

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, you can use `document.getElementById("sell").setAttribute("disabled", false);` inside a function you call onclick on your button

Comment: <label for="price">Price</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" placeholder="HKD" disabled>

I update my code with the 'price' section. Sorry for my miss.